# Too slow start up with Atmega2560 on custom PCB

Tags: arduino-mega

I have some several custom PCB's based on Atmega 2560.
I am using AVRISP MarkII for flashing. No bootloader.

Flashing is flawless, it just works. I have one assembled PCB works as it should be, no issues.

But, the other one has a quite time lag in its functions.
It has also been flashed OK but, it is not running quite OK.

**Here are my observations;**

By asserting Reset, I expect four leds on the pcb running (on and then off) by 100ms intervals one after each others. This is happening in the very beginning in Setup() section of the program.

**Note that:** Leds are connected to MCU via mosfets. If MCU output is LOW, they are ON and vice versa.

So, with this problematic PCB, all leds come ON all together after 10 seconds after pressing reset button and they stay almost 60 seconds before they start the sequence (on and then off) as coded.

And then that sequence is also slowly occurring. It is not 100ms as I coded but almost 4 seconds or so.

I am suspecting from the external clock (16Mhz) circuitry but I can't proof it accurately as I don't have oscilloscope at hand.

You may see the simple code I use to test that behavior;

```
void TestLeds() {
    unsigned long interval = 100;

    digitalWrite(LED1_PIN, LOW);
    delay(interval);
    digitalWrite(LED1_PIN, HIGH);
    delay(interval);

    digitalWrite(LED2_PIN, LOW);
    delay(interval);
    digitalWrite(LED2_PIN, HIGH);
    delay(interval);

    digitalWrite(LED3_PIN, LOW);
    delay(interval);
    digitalWrite(LED3_PIN, HIGH);
    delay(interval);

    digitalWrite(LED4_PIN, LOW);
    delay(interval);
    digitalWrite(LED4_PIN, HIGH);
}
```

How/where should I check the bottle-neck on that?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

To be more specific, I add this output regarding programming;
[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/77f1mig7q91d34j/Output%20of%20Programming%20with%20AVRISP%20mkII.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Measure voltage and current.

Comment: Did you change the fuses? By default most AVR run at 1MHz from the factory. So that would mean your code runs 16 times as slow.

Comment: @Gerben <pedantic> You mean a sixteenth of the speed, not sixteen times as slow. Sixteen times as slow as what? </pedantic>

Comment: I am just using same setup (fuses) as I used for the other PCB. But, how about this: if the external oscillator (16Mhz) doesn't work for some reason although the flashing has just worked fine, could there be something happened about the fuses e.g. automatically adjusted itself or so and started to work at 1Mhz instead?

Comment: @Mikael Patel: Can you be more specific about measuring voltage and current? What to measure and compare to what and to find out what eventually? Thanks.

Comment: Fuses don't reset themselves. There also no failover in case the crystal isn't working. You could try reading the fuses to verify that they are set correctly.

Comment: @majenko that's the way we say it in my language. Appearantly it doesn't translate into English. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Gerben It's also how a lot of native English speakers say it, despite it being completely incorrect 

Comment: @Gerben: I can't get it. If I use same fuses for the other identical PCB design and it works just fine, why I would check the fuses again if they don't reset themselves? I am obviously missing a point here. Can you be more specific if you still insist for checking fuses? (which I will check anyway) Thank you.

Comment: Maybe something went wrong when you set the fuses, and so that they have their original value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am closing the case. It is not 100% satisfaction though. Because, using Visual Studio with Visual Micro didn't help me on that issue in a natural way but something else.

For the future reference for somebody might get benefit out of this, I like to explain here what I did to get over this issue briefly. As @Gerben (big credits go to him) has pointed the right direction, I did check fuses by installing Atmel Studio 7 and use its programmer.

Yes, the fuses were completely wrong. I have therefore read the fuses from my healthy PCB and noted aside and then applied these very same fuse settings to the slow working PCB. I have just programmed the fuses, Firmware was the one I programmed earlier in the uC. So, voilà, the slowness has gone.

I think I am going to use Atmel Studio 7 now on next to Visual Studio as it has everything built-in including Arduino support.

Thanks everybody involved.

Answer (score 0):

Just burn the bootloader via  arduino ide before you burn your firmware. During bootloader burning, ide also configures the fuse bits you needed.

Comment: That's what I do. Then Upload Using Programmer to load without having the bootloader called.

Comment: I must agree with you guys. I do it at home with my hobby projects. The way I choose as stated in my solution has been already liked by the field engineers of ours. I can't ask them to use Arduino IDE to deploy new firmware versions. They used to use Atmel Studio flasher. Thanks anyway.